# Forms authentication for xml files

Tags: asp.net, xml, security, forms-authentication

I was wondering if you could protect xml files through forms authentication in ASP.NET 3.5.
I have some licensekeys that are found online, but you shouldn't be able to download them unless you are logged on.

For aspx pages this works automatically but not for xml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the xml files in a certain folder, add web.config to this folder containing:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow roles="admin"/>      
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Change the '?' (which means anonymous users - i.e. not logged in users) to '*' in order to deny all users (the server will have access [e.g. via Server.MapPath etc.]).

Respectively you can play with the roles or remove this line.

Also, consider that in the web.config file you can deny and allow specific extensions as follows:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.xml" />
      <!--or-->
      <add verb="*" path="*.xml" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Please don't rely on this last snippet till you make sure what are your needs.
You can find out more on [Http Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903367(VS.71).aspx), or take a look at [How to: Register HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx).

I also noticed someone asked a similar question [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/216544.aspx), you may find it helpful.

Hope you to find your quickly find your solution, good luck!